# Curly Braces Meaning

Tags: bash

I'm not sure I understand the meaning of curly braces relevant to grouping.  The only thing I can see that is supposed to be different from using regular () is that {} means execute in the current shell rather than a sub-shell.  But having tested this, there seems to be some way to format your data inside of {} which is different from regular ().  So for example, I tested the following:

```
$ {who}
bash: {who}: command not found
[john@pc ~]$ 
[john@pc ~]$ {who;}
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
[john@pc ~]$ {who ;}
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
[john@pc ~]$ { who ;}
john    tty1         2022-11-30 14:51
```

So clearly there is some sort of structure to using {}, but I can't find any resources to explain that to me online or in my book.  Can anyone help me understand it.

Comment: A big part of the difference is that `{` and `}` aren't special characters in the same sense that `(` and `)` are. `(` and `)` *always* have some sort of special meaning unless they're quoted or escaped, but `{` and `}` can be -- or be part of -- normal shell "words" (command names, arguments, etc). If you run `echo {`, the `{` is passed to `echo` as a normal argument. If you run `echo (`, you'll get a syntax error because `(` cannot be part of a normal argument unless it's quoted or escaped.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping

Answer (score 3):

The `{ }` syntax is named a *grouping* expression.

It is different from *subshell* `( )` that spawn a new shell.

Note that this syntax need space around `{` and `}` and a `;` to finish *inline* expression, like:

```
{ grep user /etc/passwd | awk '1'; }
```

Not needed in multiline expression:

```
{
    grep user /etc/passwd |
        awk '1'
}
```

This syntax is a useful way to combine many command to one stream:

```
{ cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; } | grep ...
```

Recommended links:

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Command_grouping
- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping

---

**To be not confused with *brace expansion*** like `{1..9}`

Comment: Is there anything I can search for online to understand this syntax?  Like I just saw a post online with someone using:

    echo {1..10}

And then this seems to print numbers 1-10.  But like, there feels like I haven't read something on how to use {}.  Even the man page for echo doesn't explain {}

Comment: Added link in my response

Comment: Oh man, that link is a godsend. Thanks!

Comment: @SottoVoce  I believe there must be a semi-colon after the `exit 1;`

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Good point, thanks.

Comment: Another use for the curly braces is a block of code to perform in case of failure: `cd /path/to/my/dir || { echo "$0: Error: could not chdir to /path/to/mydir" >&2; exit 1; }` Works for success too: `cd /path/to/mydir && { echo "Yay you are here"; }`